# Where is the right way to write Where AND condition query in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Who can help me write the right `WHERE AND` condition? Or if it's right, what is the difference?

1.

```
get_primary_status = Trustee.select(:id).where(:secret_key => seckey, :user_id => user_id, :primary_trustee => '1')
```

2.

```
get_primary_status = Trustee.select(:id).where(:secret_key => seckey).where(:user_id => user_id).where(:primary_trustee => '1')
```

3.

```
get_primary_status = Trustee.select(:id).where('secret_key = (?) AND user_id = (?) AND primary_trustee = (?)', seckey, user, '1')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between these three snippets (if you don't use any JOINS that can make column names in third one ambiguous).

You can confirm it by calling them in Rails console and looking at generated SQL code.

I think the first one is most readable.

Answer (score 1):

The first one.

For 2nd: as long, as you don't need dynamically add conditions, avoid chaining of 'where' functions.

For 3rd: whiting raw SQL may be good idea in some cases. But what if you will use SQLite for prototype, and PostgreSQL for going to production? Yep, they use SQL language as a standard, but [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) gives good abstraction over it.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using the [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem, even though ActiveRecord works fine here, if you were to have multiple ORs and ANDs in the query, the command is not always very readable

This is how your request would look in Squeel

```
Trustee.select(:id).where { (secret_key == seckey) & (user_id == my_user_id) &  (primary_trustee == '1') }
```

Comment: and that's worse to read than all three of the examples provided, plus it doesn't answer the question.